# New type of admin form fields

Tags: magento-1.8, adminform

I wanted design my admin from with following field type

[image]

Can any one tell me How can I implement this in Magento admin form.?
How Edit/new will work with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need a custom renderer for the field.
you can create your own class, let's call it `[Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_Friendly_Multiselect`.
This class can extend `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Multiselect`.
And all you have to do is to rewrite the `getElementHtml` in your class so you can append your second multselect and the buttons between them.

Then, in order to use this in your form you should add this in your form file right after `$fieldset = $form->addFieldset(`

```
 $fieldset->addType(
        'friendly_multiselect',
        Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('[module_alias]/adminhtml_friendly_multiselect')
    );
```

then you can define your field like this

```
$fieldset->addField(
   'field_name_here',
   'friendly_multiselect',
   array(configurations go here)
);
```

Then all your fields with type `friendly_multiselect` should be rendered using your class.